# "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed" using ftp_put on PHP

Tags: php

I am getting this error when I run my code.

> ftp_put(http://domain.com) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Here is my code:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: or insufficient permissions to write

Answer (score 0):

[ftp_put](http://php.net/ftp_put) does not work on HTTP streams. You'll need an FTP connection opened using [ftp_connect](http://php.net/ftp_connect) and [ftp_login](http://php.net/ftp_login).